# In Swift, can I detect if a CLLocation is valid or not?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am passing a location to another `UIViewController` which has a `MapView` using `prepareForSegue`. I call this `receivedLocation`. The map centers on the location that is passed. If the user clicks a button to take them to the map without first sending a location, won't this fail?

How can I test to see if `receivedLocation` actually contains data, so that I can set the map to center on something else if it's empty?

Would creating a Boolean variable, and initially setting it false but turning it to true when passing a location and testing *that* work as I desire?

I see something called `CLLocationCoordinateIsValid` is available, but its parameter is a 2DCoordinate, where I run into the same problem of testing whether or not `receivedLocation`.

I'm fairly new at this and tried looking for an answer already but couldn't find an appropriate one. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class mapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var notes: UITextView!

    var receivedLocation = CLLocation()
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    var currentManager:CLLocationManager!

    var latitute:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees()
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        notes.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0

        currentManager = CLLocationManager()
        currentManager.delegate = self
        currentManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        currentManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(receivedLocation.coordinate) {

            latitute = receivedLocation.coordinate.latitude
            longitude = receivedLocation.coordinate.longitude
            annotation.coordinate.latitude = receivedLocation.coordinate.latitude
            annotation.coordinate.longitude = receivedLocation.coordinate.longitude
            map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        } else {

            latitute = currentManager.location.coordinate.latitude
            longitude = currentManager.location.coordinate.longitude
        }

        var latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        var lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        var location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitude)
        var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)       
        map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    }
```

So far this is not working for me. CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid always returns true and centers around an island, as well as adds an annotation to that weird spot.

Comment: @CodyLucas If you only want to check the valid location than you can use 'CLLocationCoordinateIsValid' function as you mentioned in your question as well. Here is sample code in swift

`var location = CLLocation()

var isValid = CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(location.coordinate)`

to understand the problem more deeply required your source code here.

Comment: I don't get it. What is `receivedLocation` that you refer to in that code? Show its declaration.

Comment: @matt sorry, don't know why I stopped at viewDidLoad()... here you are.

Comment: Good, working on an answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, do not needlessly put a useless `CLLocation()` into `receivedLocation`. Declare `receivedLocation` as an implicitly unwrapped *Optional*:

```
 var receivedLocation : CLLocation! = nil
```

That way, either someone has set it or they have not. If they have not, it is nil, and you can test that:

```
if receivedLocation != nil {
    // okay, it's a real location!
}
```

Second, your `else` is never going to work, because it takes time for the sensors to warm up and get a location - in fact, they may never get one. So I can pretty well guarantee that in the case where `receivedLocation` *is* nil, `currentManager.location` will not be any use either. (See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042907/341994) for an explanation, and pointer to sample code, of how to use a location manager to get a single location value.)

Comment: Excellent, you got that working. As for the else, receivedLocation only has a value once a button is pressed. If they go to the map without pressing it, this is meant to handle that. Now my only issue is that if I add an annotation and then leave the MapView and come back, the annotation is gone. You don't have to answer, because this is a separate question, but if you have time, what could solve that?

Comment: No, you are right, it is a separate question. Please feel free to ask your other question as a separate question! More questions is good. (Are good.) As you will discover, Stack Overflow is very well designed for single-issue questions - the question / comment / edit / answer cycle that we just used works perfectly (as you can see!). If you ask a further question _in_ a comment, things just get out of hand.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Matt! Have a fantastic night.